# Failure to run Play Framework project from Eclipse, after "eclipsify"

Tags: eclipse, playframework

I created a small Play project. Initially, I was able to load it in Eclipse (using play eclipsify...), and run the app from Eclipse.

After few cycles of development (made outside Eclipse), I made an attempt to get back to Eclipse - and failed.

After running "play eclipsify ..." and importing the project into Eclipse: there is no "Run" configuration automatically generated, so "Run Configurations..." asks me to define stuff from scratch. I understand that's not what I should expect from the integration.

The project files seem to be loaded correctly, it's just about the lack of ability to perform Run operation.

Any hint how to debug the problem, or how to "clean" Eclipse environment - would be appreciated.

Using Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1 Build id: 20110916-0149, Play 1.2.4 on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found the issue.

Eclipse configuration do not support well the "custom" application.name, different than the project name.
For example, in 'yabe' tutorial, I changed to:
application.name=Yet Another Blog Engine

Once I replaced (in 'Yet Another Blog Engine.launch' ) - all the references to the customized name, back to 'yabe' - I was able to run this configuration from Eclipse.

A bug in 'eclipsify'?

Max

Answer (score 0):

after play -eclipsify command try to delete your eclipse project and to reimport it from scratch.
This normally fixes most issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
play clean <yourProject>
play eclipsify <yourProject>
```

And then it can happen that you need to delete the project from the workspace and re-import it again. I was not in a need to do that, ever.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case... It happened to me that I wasn't running the commands with the appropriate permissions... Play wasn't detecting this for some reason.... But to fix it, make sure you run as a superuser, or that the user you are running the command as has writing permissions to that folder. To expand on adis answer I did something like this and it worked...

```
sudo play clean <yourProject>
sudo play eclipsify <yourProject>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up sbt (simple build tool) to build the application.
After successfully building the app, hit run.
Then go to the address it gives in a browser.
Most likey localhost:XXXX.